# GeoServer: Legend title with single feature layer

Tags: geoserver, legend, css

Been working with GeoServer for some time now. While working with the publishing tab of the layer, I noticed a problem.  Every time that I set the default style with a single featured CSS style, the defined title doesn't show. For some clarification I've added some screenshots:

- The first image shows the desired visualization. Notice the two titles in the legend
- The second image shows the desired style but not the title, this always happens if a layer is only styled by one feature.

I would like to figure out a way to make my titles visual in all my layers, can anyone help me out?

[image: This image shows the 'good' visualization.]

[image: This image shows the good style but not the title like the other image.]

Comment: did you give your rule a title in the 2nd case?

Comment: Yes, /* @title  Telfort-BT Ignite */. Same as any other title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to add a second category with no data to allow geoserver show the legend title, for example in QGIS:[image: Picture 1]